# Como puedo enviar informacion de la base de datos al navbar de mi aplicacion

Tags: c#, blazor

Estoy creando un aplicacion con blazor, quiero que en el menu uno de los elementos tenga un badge y ese badge tenga un numero entero que representa las aprobaciones pendientes, tengo un api que me brinda la informacion necesaria, trato de acceder al api mediante el metodo OnInitialized, pero este no se ejecuta

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await GetArticles();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        approvesArticles = 0;
    }
}

private async Task GetArticles()
{
    var httpResponse = await _repository.Get<RequestResponseWrapper<int>>($"api/Article/GetApproveCount");
    var requestManager = new RequestManager<int>(httpResponse);

    if (requestManager.Error)
    {
        approvesArticles = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        approvesArticles = requestManager.Response;

    }
}
```

}

este es el componente

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que utilizas NavBar en un Layout y luego tienes Pages que usan este Layout.
El Layout es una cosa fija y replicable y no es viva. Le puedes añadir codigo, porque es un componente razor, pero cuando lo marcas que sera un layout, su codigo se deshabilita, ya que no se ejecuta junto con la aplicación.

Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es no usar Layout sino un componente y dentro de este componente le pasas cualquier HTML que quieres.

```
<MiLayoutConBadge>
   <label>Hola mundo</label>
</MiLayoutConBadge>
```

Otra opción que puedes usar es cear un JavaScript que al cargar la pagina siempre se ejecuta y llama a la API que tu quieres y obtenga valores para poner en el NavBar.